# Langdetect Issue With pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm trying to compile my code in oython that uses the library langdetect into a .app with pyinstaller.

as answered in this question : https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2680

I modified the .spec file to include this :

```
a = Analysis(
# your other stuff here...
datas=[
    ('langdetect/utils', 'langdetect/utils'),  # for messages.properties file
    ('langdetect/profiles', 'langdetect/profiles'), # don't forget if you load langdetect as a submodule of your app, change the second string to the relative path from your parent module. The first argument is the relative path inside the pyinstaller bundle.
      ]
# the rest of your analysis spec...
)
```

But pyinstaller stil does not find utils. I think that I didn't enter the right path in the tuple, but I don't know what I'm supposed to do (the program is supposed to already 'be' in the libraries directory, so shouldn't it work in theory ?)

I used anaconda anaconda to install langdetect. The problem is that I'm not using my laptop to build the .app file, so I would refer if it's a generic path rather than specific.

thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The issue was with the langdetect library. I used textblob library instead  and it worked perfectly.